# Ionic 4 and Angular 8 CanActivate Route with lazy loading

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

In angular 7 on my app-routing.module.ts page I could do this to set my authguard on pages.

```
{ path: 'join', loadChildren: './pages/team/join/join.module#JoinPageModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
```

However, now that angular 8 uses the import method how do I set canActivate on my pages?

```
 {
    path: 'join',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/team/join/join.module').then( m => m.JoinPageModule)
  },
```

Comment: do you get any error when you do this? {
    path: 'join',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/team/join/join.module').then( m => m.JoinPageModule), canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  path: 'join',
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  loadChildren: () => import('./pages/team/join/join.module').then(m => m.JoinPageModule)
}
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by the addition of some explanation of how and why they work.